# Which music theme plays at the end of the Naruto vs Sasuke fight?

Tags: naruto, music

Which music theme is it at the timestamp 1:15:10 in this YouTube Link: [Naruto vs Sasuke Full Fight English Dub](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=slhktk8eXiU&t=1h15m10s) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the *exact* version of the track during the scene you linked, may have been an unreleased variation of the official track. This is also played [during Sasuke's flashback when he's pinned down by Naruto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=slhktk8eXiU&feature=youtu.be&t=2590).

The title of the official track is [Oh! Student and Teacher Affection (Aa, Shiteiai)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNHrZbPLY5g) and appears on Naruto OST 3, track 9.

Comment: But OST 3, track 9 is not the same.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto It's from the [Original Naruto OST 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O7Cq5Ifsz6E). There is also a [Shippuden OST 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fniTt4ylQO8), which is different

Answer (score -1):

This is the sound track you were looking for:
https://soundcloud.com/anasourik/kaze-to-honoo-no-rondo

Comment: No it's not the correct one. The correct one is "Oh! Student and Teacher affection". Check the accepted answer.